# How to change the auto-generated name of controller in MVC 5 to our choice?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, ef-code-first

I'm currently creating an MVC project. I'm trying to add a new MVC 5 Controller with Views, using Entity Framework. But the thing is, i tried to have 2 different controllers that refers to one model: each with different requirements.

> 1) Model Class: Customer
>
> Data Context Class: DbContext1
>
> Controller name: WalkInCustomerController
>
> 2) Model Class: Customer
>
> Data Context Class: DbContext1
>
> Controller name: OnlineCustomerController

But it won't let me change the automatically generated controller name: 'Customer'. Popup error:

> There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of the invocation.'

Comment: The error message is too general to be analyzed, check inner exception part of the popup error by clicking "View Detail", then include it in your question.

Comment: Add some code? @Nurul

Comment: @ViVi Is my example confusing? I've changed it to OnlineCustomer and WalkInCustomer. Sorry but i don't catch you, should i modify the code after i added the controller? The problem is: in the popup scaffolding window, i can't add the controller when i changed the original auto-generated controller name given. Visual Studio auto-generated patientController for me, but the thing is, i needed to create 2 different controllers out of patient model: OnlineCustomer and WalkInCustomer.

Comment: @ViVi i just retried the process and suddenly it works haha weird..but anyways thanks for your willingness to help

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto i just retried the process and suddenly it works haha weird..but anyways thanks for your willingness to help